# Asp.net custom http handler before another ashx http handler

Tags: asp.net, web, web-config, httphandler

I have written an .ashx http handler. I also have a custom http handler which I added to the web.config file:

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="AspxHandler"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

and I want the call to go to my custom http handler before it goes to the ashx http handler.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Handlers in ASP.NET are endpoints, so there can be only one per request. You can
t really do something and then pass it along. If you want your handler to run instead of the regular page handler then first remove the default ASPX handler and then add yours. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903367%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) for the config file schema.

If you want to just run something before a handler and possible affect which handler runs, you need to implement an IHttpModule